# Using a 'for ... else' statement to return the loop variable

Tags: python

I have this `for...else` statement code:

```
def someFunction():
    for i in range(first, last):
        if condition:
            return i
    else:
        return i + 2
```

So I want to return the loop variable if certain condition happened. But if loop finished without problem then `i + 2` is returned instead.

The code works fine, but the ide is giving me a warning that "Local variable 'i' might be referenced before assignment".

so is there a better way to write my code?

Comment: What do you want to return in case the range is empty?

Comment: that is because in case the range turn out to be empty, `i` could not be aasigned any value and you would get and exception as result

Comment: that's equivalent to `else: return last +1`, no?

Comment: If the loop fails , what value does i return from else block?

Comment: It is a part of a function, sorry I edited my question

Comment: @njzk2 this the best answer, Thanks. And the else statement is actually not needed at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the warning from your ide is because of this case

```
>>> for i in []:
        print(i)
    else:
        print(i)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#94>", line 4, in <module>
    print(i)
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
>>>
```

In case your range turn out to be empty then the for loop would neither create the `i` variable and assign it a value.

to get rip of the warning, and the potential exception, first assign `i` with some default value, like i=0 before you do the loop

Answer (score -4):

style 1:

```py
var = range(first, last)

for i in var:
    if condition:
        return i
else:
    return list(var)[-1] + 2  # <last-val> + 2
```

style 2:

```py
for i in var:
    if condition:
        return i
if len(var):
    return i + 2  # outside the 'else'
```

Comment: "style 2" has the same issue as what the OP wrote

Comment: Why are you using `list(var)`??

Comment: `list.__init__(...)` takes a iterable and get items from that. `range` object can be iter.

Comment: @Delta but **why**? You can just use the range object

Comment: for index,`range()` is the better, for index and item [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and item only, don't use anything and just use the varible.